# Porting Buildroot project from Ubuntu 14.04 to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, embedded-linux, glib, buildroot, meson-build

I am maintaining a Buildroot-2015.02 based project that is currently being built on Ubuntu 14.04. The OS needs to be updated to Ubuntu 20.04, but I am having difficulties getting everything working. Most of the problems seem to be related to newer versions of gcc and glibc on Ubuntu 20.04. I was able to overcome a lot of the problems by replacing some packages, e.g., e2fsprogs with the corresponding packages from the latest Buildroot version on GitHub.

I also needed to update libglib2, but after pulling the latest libglib2 package from Buildroot, I get the following error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'libglib2'.  Stop.
```

I was able to figure out that the root cause for this was caused by [this](https://github.com/buildroot/buildroot/commit/4102db0f7a75ecdef3073dd65a5d2cfd512d984c#diff-1f42b2f47615d610c6cf7136d034212cfff84323ace1b7f18e0eae7b29be6f15) commit, where the package type was changed from autoconf to meson:

```
-$(eval $(autotools-package))
-$(eval $(host-autotools-package))
+$(eval $(meson-package))
+$(eval $(host-meson-package))
```

Now I cannot figure out how to continue from here or if I even have the right approach to this. Ideally, I would like to change as little as possible in the project.

Comment: Your build error line indicates it's an error in `make` - based buildsystem. Therefore not in Meson… Aside of that - `libglib2` name is a package name, not a pkg-config dependency name - try replacing it with `glib-2.0`.

Comment: @PatrykObara he's using buildroot, a operating system build tool. Buildroot uses both make and the name libglib2. The issue is likely that he's trying to use latest packages with six years old buildroot tools... this is unlikely to work